# как сделать так чтобы получить массив объектов только по цвету глаз?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой масив обьектов

```js
'use strict';
const users = [
  {
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
    name: 'Carey Barr',
    email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    guid: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
    name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
    email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 38,
  },
  {
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
  },
];
```

мне нужно вивести пользователей по цвету глаз 'blue'вот мое решение задачи

```js
'use strict';
const users = [
  {
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
    name: 'Carey Barr',
    email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    guid: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
    name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
    email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 38,
  },
  {
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
  },
];


const getUsersWithEyeColor = (users, color) => {
  return users.filter(color => color.eyeColor === 'blue');
};

console.log(getUsersWithEyeColor(users, 'blue'));
```

при этом мне выводит 3 пользователя у которых голубые глаза,

```js
[
  {
    "id": "701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081",
    "name": "Moore Hensley",
    "email": "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "friends": [
      "Sharron Pace"
    ],
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": 2811,
    "skills": [
      "ipsum",
      "lorem"
    ],
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 37
  },
  {
    "id": "7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1",
    "name": "Sharlene Bush",
    "email": "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "friends": [
      "Briana Decker",
      "Sharron Pace"
    ],
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": 3821,
    "skills": [
      "tempor",
      "mollit",
      "commodo",
      "veniam",
      "laborum"
    ],
    "gender": "female",
    "age": 34
  },
  {
    "id": "334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70",
    "name": "Carey Barr",
    "email": "careybarr@nurali.com",
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "friends": [
      "Jordan Sampson",
      "Eddie Strong"
    ],
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": 3951,
    "skills": [
      "ex",
      "culpa",
      "nostrud"
    ],
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 27
  }
]
```

но совсеми другими параметрами , а мне нужно только поле со цветом глаз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
'use strict';
const users = [
  {
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
    name: 'Carey Barr',
    email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    guid: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
    name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
    email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 38,
  },
  {
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
  },
];


const getUsersWithEyeColor = (users, color) =>
  users.filter(user => user.eyeColor === color).
  map(user => ({ eyeColor: user.eyeColor }));

console.log(getUsersWithEyeColor(users, 'blue'));
```

Comment: я что то не подумала про map) спасибо за подсказку

Comment: я вас отблагодарила)

Comment: @hzybodska Пожалуйста. И я Вас  :)